# What does "Register MyApp.app" means in the Xcode Build log?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I am developing a project for macOS. The project is very small so far, and it uses macOS storyboards, Swift and Objective-C. I noticed abnormal delays while building, even with a very small change to the codebase, and found out, in the Xcode Build log, that there is the last entry:

```
Register MyApp.app
```

That takes 31 seconds to execute. Does anybody know what it can be and how it can be made faster ? Many thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

I expanded the entry in the log, it says:

```
RegisterWithLaunchServices /Users/fofo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Myapp-augvduoefsyddebwifpwnceelymu/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It usually helps to delete “DerivedData” folder

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help for me. Thanks